# a python for loop only executing methods in a class with the last list of values passed

Tags: python, loops, class

I tried looping a list of values in a class but the methods only execute the expected output with the last list of the values in the loop

```py
class Grading():
    perfomance = {}
   
    
    def __init__(self,name,math,eng ,kis ,sci ,sos ):
        self.name = name
        self.math = math
        self.eng = eng
        self.kis = kis
        self.sci = sci
        self.sos = sos
        self.find_total_marks()
        self.find_avg_marks()
        self.find_grade()
        self.insert_results()
        

    def find_total_marks(self):
        self.total = self.math + self.eng + self.kis + self.sci + self.sos
        
        
       
    def find_avg_marks(self):
        self.avg_marks = self.total / 5
        
        
       
    def find_grade(self):
        if self.avg_marks > 79:
            self.grade = "A"
        elif self.avg_marks >= 60 and self.avg_marks <= 79:
            self.grade = "B"
        elif self.avg_marks > 49 and self.avg_marks <= 59:
            self.grade = "C"
        elif self.avg_marks >= 40 and self.avg_marks <= 49:
            self.grade = "D"
        else:
            self.grade = "E"
       

    def insert_results(self):
        self.perfomance["name"] = self.name
        self.perfomance["total"] = self.total
        self.perfomance["avarage_mks"] =self.avg_marks
        self.perfomance["grade"] = self.grade
results = []
perfomance_out = []

for i in range(1,int(input("Enter no of students: "))+ 1):
    
    inputs = [input("Enter name \n"),
        int(input("Mathematics: ")),
        int(input("English: ")),
        int(input("Kiswahili: ")),
        int(input("Science: ")),
        int(input("Social Studies: "))]
    results.append(inputs)
    Grading(*inputs) 
    s = Grading
    perfomance_out.append(s.perfomance)

print(results)
print(perfomance_out)
```

That's part of the code, it should be printing the name of every student with the scores in a list and performance in terms of grade in another list but each student performance is equal to the last students performance

Comment: Post Grading too.

Comment: Oh, wait, if Grading is a class, in `s = Grading` you're assigning to s a class object, not the  object created in the previous line, which get's lost.

Comment: Your line: `Grading(*inputs)` does nothing. Whatever it does, the result is thrown away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Post the code for whatever Grading is.</strike>

Also try to change

```py
Grading(*inputs) 
s = Grading
```

to

```py
s = Grading(*inputs)
```

### Update

I see what's wrong now.

```
import random


class Grading():
    performance = {} # This is a class variable, shared between all instances
   
    
    def __init__(self,name,math,eng ,kis ,sci ,sos ):
        self.name = name
        self.math = math
        self.eng = eng
        self.kis = kis
        self.sci = sci
        self.sos = sos
        self.find_total_marks()
        self.find_avg_marks()
        self.find_grade()
        self.insert_results()
        

    def find_total_marks(self):
        self.total = self.math + self.eng + self.kis + self.sci + self.sos
        
        
       
    def find_avg_marks(self):
        self.avg_marks = self.total / 5
        
        
       
    def find_grade(self):
        if self.avg_marks > 79:
            self.grade = "A"
        elif self.avg_marks >= 60 and self.avg_marks <= 79:
            self.grade = "B"
        elif self.avg_marks > 49 and self.avg_marks <= 59:
            self.grade = "C"
        elif self.avg_marks >= 40 and self.avg_marks <= 49:
            self.grade = "D"
        else:
            self.grade = "E"
       

    def insert_results(self):
        self.performance["name"] = self.name
        self.performance["total"] = self.total
        self.performance["avarage_mks"] =self.avg_marks
        self.performance["grade"] = self.grade

results = []
performance_out = []
student_names = ['Student A', 'Student B', 'Student C']
student_marks = [[random.randint(1, 100) for x in range(1,6)] for _ in range(len(student_names))]


for name, marks in zip(student_names, student_marks):
    results.append([name, *marks]) 
    s = Grading(*[name, *marks])
    print(s.performance)
    performance_out.append(s.performance)

for result in results:
    print(result)

for performance in performance_out:
    print(performance)
```

since you don't want all instances to have the same performance you should move that variable to the `__init__` method:

```
import random


class Grading():
    
    def __init__(self,name,math,eng ,kis ,sci ,sos ):
        self.name = name
        self.math = math
        self.eng = eng
        self.kis = kis
        self.sci = sci
        self.sos = sos
        self.performance = {} # This is specific to each instance
        self.find_total_marks()
        self.find_avg_marks()
        self.find_grade()
        self.insert_results()
        

    def find_total_marks(self):
        self.total = self.math + self.eng + self.kis + self.sci + self.sos
        
        
       
    def find_avg_marks(self):
        self.avg_marks = self.total / 5
        
        
       
    def find_grade(self):
        if self.avg_marks > 79:
            self.grade = "A"
        elif self.avg_marks >= 60 and self.avg_marks <= 79:
            self.grade = "B"
        elif self.avg_marks > 49 and self.avg_marks <= 59:
            self.grade = "C"
        elif self.avg_marks >= 40 and self.avg_marks <= 49:
            self.grade = "D"
        else:
            self.grade = "E"
       

    def insert_results(self):
        self.performance["name"] = self.name
        self.performance["total"] = self.total
        self.performance["avarage_mks"] =self.avg_marks
        self.performance["grade"] = self.grade

results = []
performance_out = []
student_names = ['Student A', 'Student B', 'Student C']
student_marks = [[random.randint(1, 100) for x in range(1,6)] for _ in range(len(student_names))]


for name, marks in zip(student_names, student_marks):
    results.append([name, *marks]) 
    s = Grading(*[name, *marks])
    print(s.performance)
    performance_out.append(s.performance)

for result in results:
    print(result)

for performance in performance_out:
    print(performance)
```

And that's why you should post the full code from the beginning ;D the error was in the Grading class.

Comment: the solution you just gave is still providing the same output

Comment: Updated with actual answer after seeing the Grading class.